# Open Graph Protocol for categories

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I added the open graph protocol to my WordPress site. It works fine when it comes to post/pages, however, when it comes to the category page, I want to make the category name as the value of og:title but instead it fetches the post title of the latest post under the current category. How can I fetch the category name of the current category to be the value of og:title?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>
<?php $fb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumbnail'); ?>
<?php if ($fb_image) {  ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $fb_image[0]; ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/amk_default.jpg" />
<?php } ?>
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php
      if (is_single() || is_page()) { echo "article"; } else { echo "website";} ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your efforts but anyway...

Here are links to the functions used

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_name

```
echo get_cat_name( get_query_var('cat') );
```

Comment: Hi, edited my question, I've added the code I used. But it gets the title of the recent post under the category not the category name itself.

Comment: I have given you the answer you just need to add a condition if is_single() output title else my code. shuld work